# How to make changes to a live Java web service without simply deploying new services with the changes and terminating the old ones?

Tags: java, web-services

If I have a Java web service that is used as a REST endpoint, and I want to change a boolean value in the application when I make a particular update to the backing MySQL database, how would I go about doing that? Is there a means to manipulate a live web app without using the REST endpoints?

Comment: Huh... Using a database? Well, you could always read from the database whenever you suspect that there might have been a change. That's kinda the only way to do it. Are you trying to manage configurations? Runtime properties and such? If so, you may want to consider using a 3rd-party configuration library (such as [Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/)) which supports dynamic reloading.

Comment: @nasukkin not necessarily using the database. that's just there for context. what i want to do is manually make a change to the database, and then manually make a change to the live web app. i don't know if there's a way to manually make a change to the variables in a live web app.

Comment: Spring Cloud Config?

Comment: @chrylis not using Spring -- is it a requirement for using it?

Comment: You can have a timer, that read that mysql db, and do the necesary tasks

Comment: if im not mistaken you are deploying jar or war file?

Comment: do your project has a jar file generated as a package?

Comment: when im using asp.net web service i just clean and build then get the dll and copy paste to deployment server.

Comment: @reds no, why? if i had my own jar file in the project structure it could help solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not saying that it could make you solved this problem but possibly.